# Unbind a shortcut from plugin_customization.ini

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I create an eclipse product which contains 2 plugins: 1 created by me, 1 external.
The external plugin overrides some basic shortcuts ( ctrl+z, ctrl+v), even in my own defined scheme.
Is it possible to unbind a shortcut from `plugin_customization.ini`?

Comment: How is the external plugin doing these overrides?

Comment: @greg-449 It's unclear to me. It's the CDT plugin which overrides the `Ctrl+z` to go to `EOF`.

Comment: Have I understood it correctly: you want to disable a shortcut defined by `plugin_customization.ini` in your own plugin (which does not contain a product definition)? Why not just use your own `plugin_customization.ini` and start Eclipse with `-pluginCustomization <path to plugin_customization.ini file>` (or change `eclipse.ini` accordingly)?

Comment: @howlger The shortcut is defined in another plugin. I have my own `plugin_customization.ini` but I don't know how to disable the shortcut from my own `plugin_customization.ini`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcuts can be specified and also unbound via `plugin_customization.ini`:

1. In ***Window > Preferences: General > Keys*** bind or unbind (by clicking the ***Unbind Command*** button) to your needs
2. Exit Eclipse
3. From the workspace **`.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs`** file copy the **line that starts with `org.eclipse.ui.commands=` with the prefix `org.eclipse.ui.workbench/` to your `plugin_customization.ini`** file

Comment: Thank you, maybe a refference to this answer should be made [here](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_cmd_bindings.htm)